# activerecords validation in ruby on rails showing multiple outputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I want to validate the presence of a filed called age. Age can not be blank and should be a number.

Here is my code snipped

```
validates_presence_of :age
validates :age, numericality: true
```

its working fine .But my problem is when age is blank output shows

- age can't be blank
- age is not a number

i don't want to print "age is not a number" when  age is blank

Comment: Try this `validates :age, numericality: true, allow_blank: true`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `allow_blank: true` to ***skip*** the validation on `numericality` when the `age` is ***blank***.

```
validates :age, numericality: true, allow_blank: true
```

You can further merge those two validations into one

```
validates :age, presence: true, numericality: {allow_blank: true}
```

There is a similar article [***here***](http://www.johndel.gr/blog/rails-numericality-validation-trick)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
validates_presence_of :age
validates :age, numericality: true, allow_blank: true
```